# Is is possible to block android location from using 3G to get location, get only from gps?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, locationlistener

This is how I start the location listener:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, REQUEST, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Where my request looks like this:

```
public LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create().setInterval(PS_MEDIUM_REQ_TIME).setFastestInterval(PS_MEDIUM_REQ_TIME)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

The issue is when I get into the metro, not having gps signal, it get the data from networking. And 3G etc, works via repeaters, so it will throw my location to the nearest data Tower. I would prefer it to simply just not give locations, in this case, cause throwing my location a couple of kilometers far away is not an acceptable case.
So my question is: is it possible to force it to accept only gps coordinates? Or to atleast check from where they come, so I know if to accept or not?

Comment: Have you tried this? `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, yourLocationListener);`

Comment: for:

       LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);

I get: cannot resolve this method.

Answer (score 3):

This is from the docs of the LocationRequest:

> Applications cannot specify the exact location sources, such as GPS, that are used by the LocationClient.

But when using the LocationManager you can request location updates specifying a location provder, for example LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.

See [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Since you need to use the FusedLocationProviderApi you might want to use the [Location.getAccuracy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) method to reject or accept location readings. The accuracy is given as 68% confidence radius. A smaller value means higher accuracy. The higher the accuracy, the more likely it was acquired using GPS.

There also is a [Location.getProvider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider()) method which returns the provider if it was set. If the provider wasn't set it will return null.

Additionally you could use [LocationRequest.setPriority(int)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority(int)) and use [LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY) as parameter to make sure you only get the most accurate readings.

Comment: I need to use Geofences in my application, hence why I  am using the LocationServices with LocationRequest. Location Manager doesn't have geofences

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT! But still it does not help me, cause it takes the location from my Network (3G, 4G, etc), which will get the location from it's provider, but being underground, and the internet being with repeaters, it will throw me at the end of the metro exit, 2-3km far from my place. But, the accuracy will remain small, around 30-60m. (in that 68% confidence radius. PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY is already set. But if it cannot take locations from GPS, it will take from networks. (I wanted to try to make it just ignore those locations. Better to not get locations at all, then false)

Comment: I just looked in the Location API doc. There's a getProvider() method. It may return null when not set but I think it's worth a shot.